# Are these two sets of measures equal?

Tags: measure-theory

Are these two sets of measures equal?

$$ A=\{\mu\in\mathcal{M}_+([0,1]) \mid \,\, \mu \ll \mathcal{L}([0,1]) \} $$

(i.e. the set of nonnegative finite measures on the sphere which are a.c. wrt the Lebesgue measure) and

$$ B=\{\nu\in\mathcal{M}_+([0,1]) \mid \,\, \nu \ll \mathcal{U}|_{[0,1]} \} $$

(i.e. the set of nonnegative finite measures on the sphere which are a.c. wrt the uniform measure on the unit interval?)

Comment: At the risk of seeming naive, is the uniform measure in $[0,1]$ not the lebesgue measure? If not, would you mind defining it?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply! So, given an interval $I=[a,a+L]$, the uniform measure on $I$ is the restriction of the Lebesgue measure to $I$, scaled by a factor $L$. This means that the two sets are actually equal: $A=B$.

Comment: It must be a bit trickier since the definition of the Lebesgue measure is not even unique, if I recall well. However, what I said before should work if we only look at the borel algebra. Right?